# letting caller function choose a color java

Tags: java, oop, colors

Hi I am trying to let the caller function choose the color of the drawing but failing.

```
Car car = new Car(400, 300, 15, Color.red)
```

and here is my car object

```
    public class Car{
    private Color color;



        public Star(double x, double y, double radius, Color color) {
            // We can call other methods inside the constructor
            setStarCoordinates(x, y, radius);
            this.color = color;
        }
public void draw(Graphics2D graphics){
        graphics.drawPolyline(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, 11);
        graphics.fillPolygon(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, 11);
        graphics.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

edit. code compiles properly but doesn't change the color
PS. i did not include some of the methods in the car object here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `color` of the `Graphics` context AFTER you've finished painting the object...

The order in which you do things is important, for example, something like

```
graphics.setColor(color);
graphics.drawPolyline(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, 11);
graphics.fillPolygon(xCoordOfStar, yCoordOfStar, 11);
```

should set the color and then, using that color, draw you shapes